# HIbernate mapping of long primitive data type member variable of pojo class to Date data type in mysql table column

Tags: hibernate

I am writing a small application in which I have long value(which represents date and time) as member variable of a `POJO` class, and the representing column filed in `mysql` database table is of `datetime datatype`. So I need to map this `long` value to `datetime` datatype column in `hbm.xml` file which automatically converts the datetime value to `long` value. So can any one help me out to solve this mapping?

For example:

```
 class Task{
    private long pickTime;
 }

 database table task_executions.
 record_id(int),pick_time(datetime)
```

so now  I need to map this `pickTime` to `pick_time` in `hbm.xml`

Comment: some sample code / output would help.

Comment: Why are you using a long datatype to store what appears to be a date/time? Switch to use either the Java Date/Calendar API (ewww) or JodaTime (YAY!). If worst comes to worst, you can express that as a timestamp.

Comment: Thnanks James Massey. any way I found one solution using formula tag